# Can a non-profit organization use a patent without paying a licensing fee if it makes no money on its own invention?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property

Can a non-profit organization use a patent without paying a licensing fee if it makes no money on its own invention? Let's assume that the company designs a chip based on the x86 architecture and then makes the design open-source. Will the non-profit company have to pay Intel for using the x86 architecture or not? Assume that this is in the United States.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Patents give exclusive rights to their owner

It doesn’t matter who wants to use it, they need the owner’s permission.

Comment: Provided that the patent is still in force. I think a patent on the x86 architecture would be long expired.

Comment: And in any case, a patent would only cover certain aspects of the x86 architecture. The key point is, if what you are doing is covered by a patent, then the fact that you're a non-profit and not making money is irrelevant; but your example doesn't sound like something that would necessarily be covered by a patent.